# How to specify the country in facebook graph api search?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, country-codes

How to specify the country in facebook graph api search
im not very tech in this, need in simple form

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Sarkozy
Then, i want to have replies only in a certain country only.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Sarkozy......?????

I have tried several methods, nothing worked out for being not knowledge in this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses geo ip to detect the country where the request came from, you should use a country proxy in order to "tell" facebook what kind of geo located results you want.